# Python Django - migrate throws django.db.utils.OperationalError: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm running the following cmd to run the initial migration of django project in my localhost(MAC) and i'm getting the following errors.

```
file "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 270, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

I'm running the postgresql properly and able to access or connect it using psycopg2.

Why it's expecting SSL in my localhost.

CMD ran

```
python3 dev.py migrate
```

My database config

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5433',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500,
        'DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode':'disable'}
    }
}
```

Please let me the root cause of the issue to fix migrations in my local.

Thanks

I tried directly connecting to the db via psycopg2